# Ubuntu 20.04 melting my computer! Slight burning smell from vent!

Tags: 20.04, bash, cpu-load, tracker

After migrating from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04, my CPU is burning hot and disk activity is off the charts, while this seemingly un-killable set of processes slams my CPU and harddisk:

```
tracker-miner-fs

tracker-extract

tracker-store
```

In the process of trying to understand what is going on, I came across this most curious behavior in a bash session:

```
user@computer:/tmp$ cd tracker-extract-files.121

bash: cd: tracker-extract-files.121: Permission denied

user@computer:/tmp$ sudo cd tracker-extract-files.121

[sudo] password for user: 

sudo: cd: command not found

user@computer:/tmp$ sudo cd tracker-extract-files.121

sudo: cd: command not found

user@computer:/tmp$ ls -al tracker-extract-files.121

ls: cannot open directory 'tracker-extract-files.121': Permission 
denied

user@computer:/tmp$ sudo ls -al tracker-extract-files.121

total 8

drwx------  2 gdm  gdm  4096 Jan 22 17:26 .

drwxrwxrwt 19 root root 4096 Jan 23 10:39 ..

user@computer:/tmp$ sudo ls -al tracker-extract-files.121/gdm

ls: cannot access 'tracker-extract-files.121/gdm': No such file or 
directory

user@computer:/tmp$ sudo ls -al tracker-extract-files.121/root

ls: cannot access 'tracker-extract-files.121/root': No such file or 
directory
```

I also tried to run the command "renice" for the running processes but the PID keep changing like it knows that I am trying to throttle it back, LOL! Creepy stuff!

```
renice -n 19 -p 170178

renice -n 19 -p 170288

renice -n 19 -p 170332

renice -n 19 -p 170333

renice -n 19 -p 170334
```

I DO like the ability to quickly search my files, especially the contents of my files, but I am not sure if it is worth the fire risk.

OK I did a little more digging as of 12:25 1/23/2022...
I ran the tracker status command on a specific .xls file and with no argument and got:

```
user@computer:~$ tracker status /home/user/Documents/Win7Backup/D_Drive/user/Libraries/Documents/Biz/Books/2017Tax.xls
Currently indexed: 170422 files, 13538 folders
Remaining space on database partition: 427.5 GB (43.47%)
All data miners are idle, indexing complete



user@computer:~$ tracker status
Currently indexed: 170422 files, 13538 folders
Remaining space on database partition: 427.5 GB (43.47%)

(tracker status:62564): Tracker-CRITICAL **: 12:15:02.297: Could not get miner progress for 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Extract': GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
All data miners are idle, indexing complete
```

Then `top` shows:

```
Tasks: 256 total,   4 running, 252 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 23.9 us,  2.7 sy, 24.1 ni, 48.3 id,  0.8 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7745.3 total,   1063.2 free,   1251.9 used,   5430.2 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   1802.3 free,    245.7 used.   6055.6 avail Mem 

    PID USER   PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                
  61542 user   20   0  366236  26704  21940 R 100.0   0.3   0:17.31 tracker-store                                                          
  61548 user   39  19 1288328  43640  32132 R  83.7   0.6   0:02.52 tracker-extract                                                        
   1595 user   39  19  593744  20784  17392 S  15.6   0.3 133:26.03 tracker-miner-f                                                        
   2149 user   20   0  823548  43020  29660 S   0.7   0.5   2:47.60 gnome-terminal-                                                        
  55506 user   20   0 2488820 179644  90648 R   0.7   2.3   1:09.15 Isolated Web Co                                                        
  61547 user   20   0   12236   4112   3388 R   0.7   0.1   0:00.05 top
```

Comment: Even if you do the above you should fix your computer's cooling problem. Your device should be able to run at a max load and cool itself without causing damage. As a safeguard, your device should also thermal throttle to prevent overheating. If you are smelling something burning, then neither of these things are happening. You can start disabling services, but that won't solve the root problem.

Comment: Thank you Arthur! I would really like to have the index since it enables searches of file contents as well. I did, however, find a command to nicely terminate in the link you sent: "tracker daemon -t" and it DOES work as long as I am logged in. But smoking my CPU for MANY days?! Isn't there a way to slow it down to 25% CPU instead of blasting multiple cores 24/7?